# Kubernetes kuberadm not using proxy

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, proxy, centos

I am using kubeadm with proxychain like this:

```
 proxychains4 kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=all
```

But when it wants to pull image from k8s.gcr.io/coredns, it was not using the proxy and connect directly to k8s.gcr.io

What should I do to force kubeadm to use a proxy for pulling images

Answer (score 1):

Can you set https_proxy and http_proxy environment variables and try.